# Can't specify the starting of some lines having required search keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to capture the `Dirección` and `Name` from the given string. The target names appear in the next line when a starting line contains `Dirección` or `Name`.

The regex I've tried with can grab the required results. However, they fail miserably when I use `^` to specify the starting position. So, I expected the regex to be `^Dirección\n(.*)` and `^Name\n(.*)` instead of `Dirección\n(.*)` and `Name\n(.*)`.

I've written so far:

```
import re

str_container = """
Dirección
Avenida 18
Name
Sapphire Elia
web
http://www.3g-office.com
Dirección
Avenida Canaval
Name
Peter Costa
web
http://www.abengoa.pe
"""

direction = re.search(r"Dirección\n(.*)",str_container).group(1)
for name in re.finditer(r"Name\n(.*)",str_container):
    print(name.group(1))
```

Expected output:

```
Avenida 18 Sapphire Elia
Avenida Canaval Peter Costa
```

> How can I specify the starting of some lines having required search keyword?

Note: It is merely an example and the real data look very different, so string manipulation is not an option.

Comment: Why are you using regex?  This looks to be a trivial string comparison for the entire line.  `line == 'Dirección\n' or line == 'Name\n'`.

Comment: For using anchors in a multiline string make sure you are using `MULTILINE` mode. Place `(?m)` before your regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
for direccion,name in re.findall(r"^Dirección\n(.*)\nName\n(.*)",str_container, re.M):
    print(f'{direccion} {name}')
# => Avenida 18 Sapphire Elia
# => Avenida Canaval Peter Costa
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GHZ4ZV).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (since `re.M` flag is used)
- `Dirección\n` - a `Dirección` word
- `(.*)` - Group 1: a whole line, empty or not
- `\nName\n` - a newline, `Name` and a newline char
- `(.*)` - Group 2: a whole line, empty or not.